# How is one meant to use the collections.abc classes with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, metaclass

I'm having an issue where I want to use the mixin methods from `collections.abc.MutableSequence`, but I also have to inherit from something else.

```py
class Thing(urwid.Pile, collections.abc.MutableSequence):
    ...
```

I end up with

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be
a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

How do I determine what's going on, and fix it? `metaclass = ABCMeta` doesn't do the trick, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`metaclass=ABCMeta` *is* the problem. `MutableSequence` is using `ABCMeta` as its metaclass, `Pile` is using something else, hence the conflict.

What you can do is inherit from `Pile` and use `MutableSequence.register()`, like this:

```
class Thing(urwid.Pile):
    ...

collections.abc.MutableSequence.register(Thing)
```

You won't get an exception if your `Thing` does not implement all the required methods, however `issubclass(Thing, MutableSequence)` and `isinstance(Thing(), MutableSequence)` will return True.

Comment: Thanks. 

   class ABCMetaWidgetMeta(urwid.WidgetMeta, ABCMeta):
       pass

And setting that as the metaclass also seemed to solve it.

Comment: @dwf: beware that `WidgetMeta` must be compatible with `ABCMeta` for your `ABCMetaWidgetMeta` to work correctly. Inheritance, sometimes, does not "just work" without any line of code

Comment: Of course. :) In this case they are completely orthogonal. WidgetMeta just does some property caching.